# java.lang.NullPointerException while deploying Java EE on Glassfish 4.1.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, glassfish-4, jpa-2.1

I'm working on a java ee web application. Everything was working fine until i use JPA in my EJB. I have been searching whole day but i got no where. 
here is my EJB

```
 Stateless(name = "SignupEJB")

public class SignupBean {
    @PersistenceContext (unitName = "mypersistenceUnit")
    EntityManager em;
    UsersEntity user=new UsersEntity();
    CountriesEntity countriesName=new CountriesEntity();
    public SignupBean() {
    }

    public List<String> getCountries(){
        List<String> countries=new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] tmp=new String[9];
        int i=0;
        for(;i<tmp.length;i++){
            tmp[i]=countriesName.getName();
        }
        countries= Arrays.asList(tmp);
        return countries;
    }
    public  void setValues(String fname,String lname, String email, String pass,
                           String country, String phno, String altmail) {
        user.setId(user.getId()+1);
        user.setfName(fname);
        user.setlName(lname);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassme(pass);
        user.setCountry(country);
        user.setPhNo(phno);
        user.setAltMail(altmail);
        em.persist(user);

    }

}
```

here is persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="mypersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>com.persistence.UsersEntity</class>
        <class>com.persistence.CountriesEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Project22"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Im using

- Intellij Idea 15.02
- Glassfish Sever 4.1.1
- JPA 2.1
- JDk 1.8

Here is server log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.PersistenceUnitDescriptor.addProperty(PersistenceUnitDescriptor.java:187)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.PersistenceUnitNode.startElement(PersistenceUnitNode.java:90)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.startElement(SaxParserHandler.java:502)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:357)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ExtensionsArchivist.open(ExtensionsArchivist.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.PersistenceArchivist.readPersistenceDeploymentDescriptor(PersistenceArchivist.java:143)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.WarPersistenceArchivist.open(WarPersistenceArchivist.java:93)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:405)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the error you see in IntelliJ logs.

Comment: Please post your error message / log entry for the null pointer exception

Comment: Antipattern here - your stateless bean has state (e.g. the `user` object)

Comment: @GyroGearless can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must not use EJB beans in that way. Container will create  any number of SignupBean beans for you. Every time you invoke SignupBean you could get another instance of it.
Remove this code:

```
UsersEntity user=new UsersEntity();
CountriesEntity countriesName=new CountriesEntity();
```

Also, dont generate id like this:

```
user.setId(user.getId()+1);
```

Set it to be autoincrement. Setting automatic generation of ids: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated

Comment: By the exception it seems to me that something with persistence.xml is wrong... EDIT: maybe try adding transaction type to persistance unit

Comment: no, adding transaction-type does'nt change anything

Comment: yes , problem was with persistence.xml , I didnt add my username and password in it. Its formal to say Thanks